# arranging images with css on a grid, in a way that's easy and does not suck

Tags: css, position

I have this grid, blocks of 58x58. Theres a background image with this grid and I want to position some images on certain blocks. So I used below code:

```
<div style="position: relative !important; right: 0px" id="div">
   <img src="/6f89ab34.jpg">
</div>
```

Wich is just pain because each element is relative to its previously one.

Is there a better smarter way to approach this problem?

For example so you can say place image 1 on row1, block 2 and place image 2 on row 3, block 4?

Comment: *!important* is a sign of failure. Learn about CSS specificity. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Comment: You should be using ABSLOUTE positioning, not RELATIVE.

Comment: relative seems to be the way to go since if the screen would resize it would stay on the same page.. i have this big image like 300x300 in size where I place the images on and want to keep them upfront this image

Comment: You want them to be positioned absolute in relation to the image.

Comment: Rubytastic - absolutely-positioned elements should be relative to their CONTAINER. You put "position:relative" on the container to tell the child elements, that use "position:absolute", that their origin is that of their CONTAINER, not the PAGE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways to handle it. I'd suggest using classes. One set positions absolutely on the x axis, the other on the y axis.

```
.tile {position: absolute;}

.x1 {left: 0px;}
.x2 {left: 58px;}
.x3 {left: 116px;}

.y1 {top: 0px;}
.y2 {top: 58px;}
.y3 {top: 116px;}
```

Then each item can be positioned with classes:

```
<div class="tile x1 y3">
```

Comment: thx this is a really cool idea, only problem is with absolute it looks at the screen window and does .. left and .. top for example. I need this grid to stay "on top" of a #container div the images should be positioned on the grid inside this container

Comment: Yes, you'd want them positioned absolute to the container, not the window.

Comment: In otherwords, it's not a problem provided your tiles are children of your #container.

Comment: Ok I had to add position:relative to the #container and it works, thx for this great Idea!

Comment: Glad it worked. I should have mentioned that part. Yes, position absolute positions elements in relation to the parent that is positioned.